# Return only one element per unique ID with only latest joined record

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, distinct-on

Suppose the following:

```
create schema bv;
create table bv.user(id bigint primary key);
create table bv.user_photo (
  id bigint primary key,
  url varchar(255) not null,
  user_id bigint references bv.user(id)
);

insert into bv.user values (100), (101);
insert into bv.user_photo values
  (1, 'https://1.com', 100),
  (3, 'https://3.com', 100),
  (4, 'https://4.com', 101),
  (2, 'https://2.com', 100);
```

I'd like to query for and build an object for every user, and include only the latest image in the result.

Here's what I have:

```
select
  json_build_object(
    'id', u.id,
    'latest_image', up.url
  ) user
from bv.user u
left join bv.user_photo up
  on u.id = up.user_id
```

However this returns:

```
[
  {"id" : 100, "url" : "https://2.com"},
  {"id" : 100, "url" : "https://3.com"},
  {"id" : 100, "url" : "https://1.com"},
  {"id" : 101, "url" : "https://4.com"}
]
```

However, the expected result is:

```
[
  {"id" : 100, "url" : "https://3.com"},
  {"id" : 101, "url" : "https://4.com"}
]
```

I've tried using `distinct`:

```
select distinct on(u.id)
  json_build_object(
    'id', u.id,
    'url', up.url
  ) user
from bv.user u
left join bv.user_photo up
  on u.id = up.user_id
order by u.id, up.id DESC
```

But my question is whether or not this is the correct approach? I feel like I shouldn't be using `distinct` in such a situation.

Comment: This *is* the correct approach and you by all means *should* be using `distinct on` in such situation. Plain `distinct` - no, `distinct on` - yes. One thing I'm missing here is that you're expecting a single array of those objects, but your query returns each object in a separate row. Is that something you overlooked, or are you showing what you expect a client library to make available when it retrieves multiple rows?

Comment: Yup, I'm using a client library, thanks

Comment: `DISTINCT ON` is right and typically simplest. There are better queries for *many* rows per user. Is that your use case? And roughly how many users would have no photo at all?

Comment: I'm trying to fetch a list of all `chat_message`s per `chat` (`chat`:`chat_message` is `1:M`). Each `chat_message` has a `user` (sender) column, each `user` may have many `user_photo` (`user`:`user_photo` is also `1:M`). So I was trying to fetch all of these chat messages by `chat_id`, and populate the `user` column, plucking only the latest (last uploaded) user photo. `distinct on` works well in this case, as you've suggested

Comment: Then we are dealing with a small selection of users and want the first of possibly many photos for each. Use a `LATERAL` subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With few photos per user, and while you return all (or most) users, `DISTINCT ON` is the best approach.
But it's typically faster to get distinct photos *before* you join:

```sql
SELECT json_build_object('id', u.id, 'url', p.url) AS "user"
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id)
          user_id, url
   FROM   user_photo
   ORDER  BY user_id, id DESC
   ) p ON p.user_id = u.id;
```

For many photos per user, an emulated index-skip scan is (much) faster. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

#### Summary array

To produce one summary array, you can skip `json_build_object()`. `json_agg()` can aggregate the row directly:

```sql
SELECT json_agg(sub) AS "users"
FROM  (
   SELECT u.id, p.url
   FROM   users u
   LEFT   JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id)
             user_id, url
      FROM   user_photo
      ORDER  BY user_id, id DESC
      ) p ON p.user_id = u.id
   ) sub;
```

Notably, all queries so far include the key "url" with a null value where no photo is found. You may want to strip the noise:

```
SELECT json_strip_nulls(json_agg(sub)) AS "users"
FROM  ...
```

#### For a small selection of users

**This** seems to be your use case.

A `LATERAL` subquery is typically faster. Also deals with *many* photos per user efficiently!

```sql
SELECT json_build_object('id', u.id, 'url', p.url) AS "user"
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT up.url
   FROM   user_photo up
   WHERE  up.user_id = u.id
   ORDER  BY up.id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) p ON true
WHERE  u.id IN (100, 101);  -- small selection
```

#### Summary array for a small selection, skipping null values

```sql
SELECT json_strip_nulls(json_agg(sub)) AS "users"
FROM  (
   SELECT u.id, p.url
   FROM   users u
   LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT up.url
      FROM   user_photo up
      WHERE  up.user_id = u.id
      ORDER  BY up.id DESC
      LIMIT  1
      ) p ON true
   WHERE  u.id IN (100, 101)  -- small selection
   ) sub;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kdY8gIr7)

#### Index

`DISTINCT ON` does not *need* an index. All other queries absolutely need an index on `user_photo(user_id, id)`. Or even, ideally:

```
CREATE INDEX ON user_photo (user_id, id DESC) INCLUDE (url);
```

Aside: Don't use the reserved word "user" as identifier. It works while schema-qualified, but fails without.

Comment: [Demo confirming advantage of doing `distinct on` early](https://dbfiddle.uk/H9NIKoJW), as this suggests.

Comment: @Zegarek: Great demo! Always better to actually see the effect.

Comment: Notably, the difference is **much more dramatic** for the actual use case of few selected users. Building on your fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/PpO3B4IB, or with a plain, un-optimized multicolumn index (not much of a difference for this): https://dbfiddle.uk/GsN-T4Tc

Answer (score 1):

This *is* the correct approach and you by all means *should* be using [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) in situations like this. Plain `distinct` - no, `distinct on` - yes:

> `SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] )` keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal.

One thing I'm missing here is that you're expecting a single array of those objects, but your query returns each object in a separate row. You need a [`json_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.13.1.1.1) to collect them: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9Q9dasEW)

```sql
select json_agg("user" order by id) as "user_array"
from(select distinct on(u.id) u.id,
      json_build_object('id', u.id,
                        'url', up.url) as "user"
     from bv.user u 
     left join bv.user_photo up
            on u.id = up.user_id
     order by u.id, up.id DESC) subquery;
```

| user_array |
| --- |
| [ {"id" : 100, "url" : "https://3.com"}, {"id" : 101, "url" : "https://4.com"} ] |